# Service cannot be converted back to ServiceBase

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, .net-4.8

I created myself a problem by linking a main .vb file to another project and then accidentally commenting out stuff like `OnStart/Stop` in the main file and `ServiceBase` in the designer. When I uncommented the lines, all service related objects give me errors.

I believe the problem is, that this code in the Designer:

```
ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase() {New ServiceMaintenance}
```

throws an error:

```
Value of type 'ServiceMaintenance' cannot be converted to 'ServiceBase'.
```

The main class appear to lose it's designer, the page (tab) doesn't come up by pressing F7. That and all the consequent errors are - I believe - related to `ServiceBase` not being established.

I checked all the code against freshly created test service and by now I don't see even a tiny difference in the code structure between the two. I checked main classs, it's designer file, the app.conf, project properties.

I don't know how to fix it, appart recreating the service again from a freshly generated service template. Though probably a very simple detail must be missing, I appreciate suggestions where to look.

Comment: Does `ServiceMaintenance` inherit `ServiceBase`? Presumably not, but it presumably should. Maybe you should create a new bare bones project and see what the differences are.

Comment: I didn't think if the relation is inheritance, but it may be. Anyhow, I've created a new blank service project from the same template and found absolutely no differences, when it comes to service related, designer and initialization code.